# Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath . I have added jaxb2 plugin

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

When i am trying to run my xsd soap request from Soap UI .I am getting this response .

I am using plugin jaxb2-maven-plugin version 1.5 and also tried changing the version but still getting same error .
Below is my pom.xml file.

Please help me in this

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Since you are having problems with [tag:soapui] you need to show how you have configured the soapui plugin. See [official documentation](https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x/) in case you need it.